# i am using core plot to draw a bar graph, i want show two color in one single bar, how to do that?

Tags: core-plot

i am using core plot to draw a bar graph, i want show two color in one single bar, how to do that? like Y value is green color from 0 to 15, and from 15 to 25 is red color, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two bar plots to make a stacked bar plot. Have the first one show the lower part of the bar (0 to 15). Set `barBasesVary` to YES on the second plot and use it to show the rest.

See the Vertical Bar Chart example in the Plot Gallery app for sample code.

Comment: by the way where i can find this example code? thanks a lot again.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg%2Fexamples%2FCorePlotGallery